# Border gradient height

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Alright, I managed to create a linear gradient effect on the border. However, I would like the gradient to 'end earlier'. By that, I want the border to fade to white at around the first paragraph.

Below you can see the current sitation and code:

[image: Current situation image]

HTML:

```
<article class="newsarticle">
    <div class="newsarticletext">
            <p class="newsarticletitle">SIZE announces project Nero</p>
                <br /><br />
            <p class="newsarticledesc">
                <b>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error</b>
                    <br /><br />
                Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    <br /><br />
                Voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
                    <br /><br />
                <b>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto</b>
                    <br /><br />
                Ut ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis.</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
.newsarticle {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 3px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-bottom: none;}
.newsarticle:before, .newsarticle:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#e1e1e1), to(#FFF));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e1e1e1, #FFF);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#e1e1e1, #FFF);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#e1e1e1, #FFF);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#e1e1e1, #FFF);
    top: -3px;
    bottom: -3px;
    width: 3px;}
.newsarticle:before {
    left: -3px;}
.newsarticle:after {
    right: -3px;}
```

Comment: [Re-consider the need for the browser prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) - only the `-webkit-` prefix is really needed these days.

Comment: @misterManSam [no it's not](http://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient).

Comment: Just giving an alternate to use `border-image` because you are working with borders. Using `background-image` for borders is good, but requires `::before / ::after` pseudo-elements to achieve the same trick.

Comment: @Jonathan - You linked the same page I did? - The webkit prefix is good for older android browser versions and is the only prefix that should really be needed. It could be omitted without too much bother, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the starting points for the colors.

```css
.newsarticle {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 3px solid #e1e1e1;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.newsarticle:before,
.newsarticle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#e1e1e1), to(#FFF));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e1e1e1 0%, #FFF 60%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#e1e1e1 0%, #FFF 60%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#e1e1e1 0%, #FFF 60%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#e1e1e1 0%, #FFF 60%);
  top: -3px;
  bottom: -3px;
  width: 3px;
}
.newsarticle:before {
  left: -3px;
}
.newsarticle:after {
  right: -3px;
}
```

```html
<article class="newsarticle">
  <div class="newsarticletext">
    <p class="newsarticletitle">SIZE announces project Nero</p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <p class="newsarticledesc">
      <b>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error</b>
      <br />
      <br />Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      <br />
      <br />Voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia
      consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam
      quaerat voluptatem.
      <br />
      <br />
      <b>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto</b>
      <br />
      <br />Ut ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui
      dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis.</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much!
I'll accept your answer as soon as StackOverflow allows me.

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternate to use `border-image` because you are working with borders. Using `background-image` for borders is good, but requires `::before / ::after` pseudo-elements to achieve the same trick.

You need `border` so it is better to use `border-image` than `background-image`.

***Using `border-image` Snippet:***

```css
.newsarticle {
    position: relative; padding: 8px;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e1e1e1 0%, #fff 50%) 1 20%;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e1e1e1 0%, #fff 50%) 1 20%;
}
```

```html
<article class="newsarticle">
    <div class="newsarticletext">
        <p class="newsarticletitle">SIZE announces project Nero</p><br /><br />
        <p class="newsarticledesc"> <b>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error</b><br /><br />
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br /><br />
          Voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.<br /><br /> 
          <b>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto</b><br /><br />
          Ut ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis.</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Good idea, `border-image` works really well here. *very very* slightly limited by [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image) for `border-image` such as no IE 10.

Comment: @misterManSam: Yes. Of course. But, works just fine on IE-11. So, if targeting modern browsers, then this is an alternate :)

Comment: Oh yeah, I would use `border-image` for this, no question :)